# C language: read input from user inside function - whats wrong at this code

Tags: c

So i want to get `input` from user into my `string` and print it:

```
char *fname ;
getname(fname);
printf("%s", &fname);

void getname(char *fnam e)
{
    fname = (char *)malloc(30);
    gets(fname);
}
```

So i have error:

> uninitialized local variable 'fname'

EDIT:

i only have this code and see whats wrong at this code, not to use different approach.

Comment: `only have this code and see whats wrong at this code, not to use different approach.` What are you expecting from us?

Comment: I cannot fine the unswer

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? Be more precise please.

Comment: 30 characters seems way too short, especially for a name. Think bigger!

Comment: See [Why is the `gets()` function so dangerous it should never be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used).

Answer (score 4):

C is pass by value. So nothing changes to `fname`. To make changes you have to pass the address.

```
getname(&fname);
```

And then

```
#define LEN 30
void getname(char **fname)
{
    *fname = malloc(LEN);
    if((*fname) == NULL ){ perror("malloc"); exit(1);}
    if(fgets(*fname,LEN,stdin)==NULL){
       fpritnf(stderr,"Error in input");
       exit(1);
    }
}
```

And the `printf` usage in this context would be

```
printf("%s", fname);
```

Don't use `gets` it's deprecated. And free the dynamically allocated memory when done working with it.

in `main()`

```
char *fname ;
getname(&fname);
printf("%s", fname);
free(fname);
```

Also casting `malloc` is unnecessary because `void*` to `char*` conversion is done implicitly.

Comment: I think that OP should be informed about `free()` and about casting `malloc`

Comment: @Michi.: Thanks.

Comment: UP, for doing that :D

Comment: Ok but why inside getname function i need to write *fname = malloc(LEN); and not fname = malloc(LEN) ? because fname is already char *

Comment: @DeanMovy.: Check the type of `fname` - it's `char**` - you will want to make changes to the `char*` - `fname` contains the address. That's why `*fname`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use 'gets', it's deprecated. 'fname' is a pointer to unitialized memory.  Use this:

```
char *fname = malloc(30);
getname(fname);
printf("%s", fname);

void getname(char *fname)
{
    fgets(fname, 30, stdin);
}
```

Comment: Even if he/she use `fgets` this still does not initialize the Pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `main()` function. C doesn't execute random code that's not inside a function. Try rewriting it to look like this:

```
void getname(char *fname)
{
    fname = (char *)malloc(30);
    gets(fname);
}
int main(void){
    char* fname;
    getname(fname);
    puts(fname);
}
```

Ok, now we can analyze it.
What happens is that when you pass a pointer (or any variable) to a function, the pointer gets copied. When you do `fname = malloc(30);`, the `fname` in the function gets set to the pointer from `malloc`, but the original `fname` in main remains the same. So when `getname` returns to `main`, `fname` still is uninitialized.

What you want to do is either allocate `fname` in main, or return a pointer from `getname`. So something like this would work:

```
void getname(char *fname)
{
    gets(fname);
}
int main(void){
    char* fname = malloc(30); // OR
    char fname2[30];
    getname(fname);
    puts(fname);
}
```

And so would this:

```
char* getname(void)
{
    fname = (char *)malloc(30);
    gets(fname);
    return fname;
}
int main(void){
    char* fname = getname();
    puts(fname);
}
```

Comment: `fname = (char *)malloc(30);` If you are correcting your answer, than please do it proper. Any way you should inform the OP about `gets` and more important is that none of this answers informs the OP about `free` and about cast of `malloc`.

Comment: The first variant is flat out broken, just like the code in the question.  Since you're using `gets()` still, that too is broken — see [Why is `gets()` so dangerous it should never be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)